# How to make overflow the cache configured using Ehcache?

Tags: ehcache

Can anyone please share the example for make the cache overflow which uses setMaxEntries method in Ehcache?

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot make sense of your question. Can you provide additional information? Ehcache version, usage scenario, ...